# Picture quality is very poor when convert from jpg to Base64String in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, base64

I am trying to take a picture and convert into Base64String. When i try to convert from jpg to Base64String, the quality of the picture is very poor.

I have tried like this:

```
  void convert64()
    {
        byte[] bytearray = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            if (imgSelected == null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((imgSelected));

                wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 40, 40, 0, 82);
                bytearray = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        strimage = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
    }




    WriteableBitmap Base64StringToBitmap(string base64String)
        {
            byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            WriteableBitmap bitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap(imgSelected);
            bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);

            memoryStream.Close();
            memoryStream = null;
            byteBuffer = null;
            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

My Output is:

[image: Output image]

Please let me give any idea to improve the image quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save your picture with the size of `40x40`, which is far too little, and you also only use `quality = 82`.
Use:

```
wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, imgSelected.Width, imgSelected.Height, 0, 100);
```

and check if it helps.

---

By the way - you should use

```
using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer)){  }
```

in your `Base64StringToBitmap` function, just like it is used in your `convert64`. You don't have to worry about closing your stream and Exceptions when you do it that way.